# Can Address Sanitizer abort immediately after an error is detected?

Tags: gcc, llvm, sanitizer, address-sanitizer

I am using a syscall checker in combination with `-fsanitize=address` and when ASAN finds a bug, it calls some syscalls (`ioctl(ISATTY)`, etc) when printing out the report. The syscall checker interrupts ASAN's ioctls and the error report is not collected properly.

What I would like is for ASAN to simply abort without printing the report, or failing that, a way to determine (using a libasan4 API call maybe) that ASAN found an error, so I can stop the syscall checker from intercepting syscalls.

Unfortunately `__asan_error_report`, `__sanitizer_set_death_callback` and `__asan_set_error_report_callback` from libasan4 all kick in after ASAN has collected the report:

```
0 __asan_error_report()
1 syscall_checker()
2 ioctl(ISATTY)
3 asan::PrintReport()
4 app_code_that_crashes()
```

And the syscall checker does not handle ASAN's `ioctl()` calls properly, so it exit()s normally, while I am hoping to keep ASAN's behavior of `abort()`ing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to intercept before report is printed by overriding `__asan_on_error` (declared in `asan_interface.h`, empty by default):

```
// User may provide function that would be called right when ASan detects
// an error. This can be used to notice cases when ASan detects an error, but
// the program crashes before ASan report is printed.
void __asan_on_error();
```

Note that due to weird Asan callback interface you'd better implement this callback in main binary (definitions in shared libraries are likely to be unable to intercept default definition from `libasan.a`).

Comment: Correct, thanks. My mistake earlier was trying to define __asan_on_error in the syscall checker (a .so lib). If I override it in the main app binary it works.

Comment: Yes, because due to interposition semantics `.so` is unable to override definition in `libasan.a` that was linked to main binary. TBH I find interface of some callbacks very clumsy for this reason (`__asan_default_options` has same problem). I've updated the answer.