# Take action before AddressSanitizer aborts the application

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, address-sanitizer

I'm using AddressSanitizer in my C++ project. I have an internal debug buffer which I'd like to be dumped on error, but currently AddressSanitizer imminently aborts the process.
Is there a way to perform a custom action before termination?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175625/can-address-sanitizer-abort-immediately-after-an-error-is-detected ?

Comment: There is [cool cppcon talk](https://youtu.be/-n9Fkq1e6sg) where this issue is resolved in cool way. You can use gdb feature to do a time travel (breakpoints to store state then when crash/exit happen restore state). Link is from my view history so sorry if I selected wrong one.